# How do I Handle multiple XSLT copy statements on same match?

Tags: xslt, copy

Are there any XSLT statements that will execute in consideration of other XSLT statements within the same stylesheet?

For example, if I have two copy statements matched to the same node (but only desire one copied node that contains the modifications declared in BOTH copy statements) is there a statement that will do this?

Assume that I cannot put all the transformations in one copy node, but instead have to use two or more.

---Clearer example---

```
//XML
<toy></toy>

//XSLT
<xsl:template  match="toy">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="label">SOME TOY</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template  match="toy">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:element name="range">
        <xsl:element name="min">200001</xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="max">999999</xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

My desired result would be a new toy node that is copied to a new file that has both things applied to it, so something like:

```
<toy label='SOME TOY'>
  <range>
    <min>200001</min>
    <max>999999</max>
  </range>
</toy>
```

Not two different copies

Is this possible?  Is there some way I can redo the first template so that will make this one outcome?

Comment: What statements are you talking about? Could you update your question with XSLT version you use, add XSL code and example of expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is rule in XSLT specification, which forbid this - [Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict).

If node fits several templates - only one template will be executed - in relation to the template import precedence, priority or document order, etc.

But you can separate it with *named* templates:

```
<xsl:template match="toy">
  <xsl:call-template name="toyAttribute" />
  <xsl:call-template name="toyElements" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="toyAttribute">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="label">SOME TOY</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="toyElements">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:element name="range">
      <xsl:element name="min">200001</xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="max">999999</xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Update:**
If you asking about only updating <toy> node with attribute and elements you don't need separate templates:

```
<!--toy template -->
<xsl:template match="/toys/toy">
    <!--copy toy node with namespaces -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy toy node attributes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <!-- add new attribute or xsl:call-template name="toyAttribute"-->
        <xsl:attribute name="label">SOME TOY</xsl:attribute>
        <!-- copy toy node child elements -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        <!-- add new elements - or xsl:call-template name="toyElements"-->
        <xsl:element name="range">
            <xsl:element name="min">200001</xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="max">999999</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--Copy node content -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which for XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<toys>
    <toy name="a">
        <toy-part/>
    </toy>
    <toy name="b">
        <toy-part/>
    </toy>
</toys>
```

will give following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><toys>
    <toy name="a" label="SOME TOY">
        <toy-part/>
        <range>
           <min>200001</min>
           <max>999999</max>
        </range>
    </toy>
    <toy name="b" label="SOME TOY">
        <toy-part/>
        <range>
           <min>200001</min>
           <max>999999</max>
        </range>
    </toy>
</toys>
```

Comment: So even though there are two COPY statements, it won't try to copy the stuff previously in the Toy node twice?  For example, <toy> may already have several children with data in it.  That must be copied first, AND then the new templates must be applied (adding attributes and some other data)

Comment: Perhaps you wouldn't have both copy statements then?  Only one would be needed, and then the toyAttribute template could just have the xsl:attribute statement in it?

Comment: @PetrakovichJ - I've updated code block. Probably I misunderstood question, what you going to achieve - add to every &lt;toy&gt; node new attribute and elements?

Comment: What I mean is that I MUST have two separate templates because they get generated at different times, but they only affect one toy node, so I needed a statement that allows me to dynamically add more templates to be applied to the one toy node.  Call-templates seems to do that for me.